# Problem on calculating simultaneous equation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am trying to understand someone's work discovering the locating position of the GPS receiver using three satellites.

Based on his investigation, he evaluated the simultaneous equation:
[image: Fig.1]

Then, by substituting the raw data (R=6378km),
[image: Fig.2]
[image: Fig.4]

He came out with the equation:

[image: Fig.3]

I got the same answer with him for the left part, but not for the right part. Can anyone try to solve the right part?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You should type your question instead of posting images...